# Convert ISCII characters to its UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, fonts

I want to convert the ascii encoded text input by my users into UTF-8 encoding, so that I can display it using any unicode font types. For example, I want to display english alphabet 'l' in ASCII  as 'ക' in Unicode. I think I would require a mapping system too, so that I can Map l to 'ക'. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Where is the ascii encoded text input by your users? Is it in a file?

Comment: @Tarik No, the user inputs the text directly to text boxes. The content would be in ASCII encoded Malayalam language. I want to convert it to equivalent unicode Malayalam. bcoz my website displays the content in Unicode. Thank You

Comment: @Tarik Or I want to merge the ascii encoding to Unicode. So that if the content is displayed using such a font, then the character 'l' would displayed as I required. Sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Please, note that font is different from encoding. The same alphabet can be displayed with different fonts which will display the same character in different style if I may say so. I revised my answer bellow with what I think is a full solution. Please, upvote if satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is in ISCII (Indian Script Code for Information Interchange). You need to convert ISCII with the proper code page to unicode. The following methods should do the job. Convert will convert a given text from one encoding to another. GetEncoding will provide you with the Encoding objects to be used by the Convert method.

Example code can be found here: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Text/ISCIIEncoding@cs/1/ISCIIEncoding@cs

Code page identifiers can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx

*public static byte[] **Convert(System.Text.Encoding srcEncoding, System.Text.Encoding dstEncoding, byte[] bytes)**
    **Member of System.Text.Encoding**
Summary:
Converts an entire byte array from one encoding to another.
Parameters:
srcEncoding: The encoding format of bytes.
dstEncoding: The target encoding format.
bytes: 
Returns:
An array of type System.Byte containing the results of converting bytes from srcEncoding to dstEncoding.*

and this

*public static System.Text.Encoding **GetEncoding(int codepage)**
    **Member of System.Text.Encoding**
Summary:
Returns the encoding associated with the specified code page identifier.
Parameters:
codepage: The code page identifier of the preferred encoding.  -or- 0, to use the default encoding.
Returns:
The System.Text.Encoding associated with the specified code page.*

As per Wikipedia Article, the code page for Malayalam is 57009

Comment: I converted the content like this `byte[] UniCodeText = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding(57009), Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.GetEncoding(57009).GetBytes(txtContent.Text));` but still not working.

Comment: The converted content isn't supported in Malayalam Unicode font

Comment: Your web page must have some encoding at the header. Could you please, have look at it?

Comment: I checked the content while debugging in Visual Studio

Comment: Subin: If your web page is in UTF-8 and the page encoding is speciied as such, then when the user fills up a textbox, it should be transmitted in UTF-8. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes no sense. Changing the encoding from ASCII to UTF-8 does not magically turn an `l` into a `ക`, it only changes the byte representation of the `l` (actually, since ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, it does not even do that here. It does nothing.)

What you probably want is some kind of [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) between the [Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet) and [Malayalam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malayalam_alphabet) alphabet, but that is something completely different.

Comment: When I use the font in ASCII/ISCII encoding, the l represents the Malayalam letter ക. However, In unicode the letter ക have a diiferent place. ie In ASCII the position of 'l' has been occupied by the letter ക in that particular font. rite? I want to map this to the position of ക in unicode. In short, I want to convert the letter l  to ക in unicode.

Comment: To corroborate Sabastien's assumption, see http://ldc.upenn.edu/myl/IndianScriptsUnicode.html Appendix 1, Transliteration of Devanagari to Roman